# What qualifies an application as frequently used?

Tags: unity, lenses, zeitgeist, applications-lens

I am aware that something called Zeitgeist is used to determine the "Most Frequently Used" part of the unity dashboard, but i was wondering what the specifics where. I know the amount of applications in this section varies, so it's not as simple as the # with the most uses today.

Is there any (relatively) simple way of expressing the rules which dictate the listing and ranking of Most Frequently Used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Basic answer

Simply put, the *Most Frequently Used* scope sorts applications by the number of times you've launched them. That is to say, if you've launched [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox) 1000 times, and [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home) 999 times, Firefox will be listed first. Even if you haven't launched Firefox in months and months.

### Technical answer

Simply put, the *Most Frequently Used* scope is a wrapper that searches a `Zeitgeist.Index` of installed applications with a result type of `MostPopularSubjects`. Zeitgeist measures this popularity with the `zeitgeist-datahub` daemon, which notices and updates its statistics each time you launch an application. You can look at the relevant lens code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity-lens-applications/unity-lens-applications-0.4/view/head:/src/daemon.vala), and the API documentation for Zeitgeist [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.10/c/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-1.0-ZeitgeistIndex.html).

Having looked at [the current Zeitgeist code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zeitgeist/zeitgeist/bluebird/view/head:/src/engine.vala), it appears `MostPopularSubjects` is a simple sort by number of accesses. Additionally, given the same number of application accesses, the applications are sorted by newest first. It's a little more complex than this, but the SQL generated for a *Most Frequently Used* request is more-or-less:

```
SELECT
  subj_id,
  MAX(timestamp) as timestamp,
  COUNT(subj_id) as num_events
FROM
  event_view
GROUP BY
  subj_id
ORDER BY
  num_events DESC
  timestamp DESC
```

Isn't open source beautiful?

Comment: To add, the application launching is logged by another daemon called `zeitgeist-datahub` which feeds this data in the main zeitgeist engine(running as the daemon). There is a [desktop-launch-listener which listens to app launching](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zeitgeist-dataproviders/zeitgeist-datahub/trunk/view/head:/src/desktop-launch-listener.vala)